# twitter bootstrap - creating a two panel modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone have any ideas of how to create a two panel modal. So for example one side would be a login form or something and the other side would be a list of what users get. Or one side would be a physical contact information div and the other side would be an email contact form. I tried to do two divs under the modal div tag and have one pull-left the other pull-right with each span5 or span6 but it didn't work. I ask because I have this issue. Also can anyone tell me why my contact form has so much space between the label and the input box? Go to scoopclassifieds.com (not trying to plug my site, can't post pics yet) and click contact us. I have placed the html mark up blow

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="contactForm" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Subject:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Message:</label><br/><br/>
                <div class="controls">
                   <textarea rows="5" class="input span4" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><input type="submit" name="contactUs" id="contactUs" class="btn" value="Contact Us" /></div></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Sorry if the code is so horribly formatted. I used cpanel text editor to develop it. I know its a bad idea but I had to do it as fast as possible to provide a live example.

Comment: Can you provide any mockup to understand the design.. in simple paint and brush will work.

Comment: kind of like the ebay.com login page. But instead of a login page it would a login modal

Comment: I think I understand what you need, why not just add a row and then two `span6`'s to split things inside that area?

Comment: I will suggest you plz use JSfiddle to paste your work. Then we are clear to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a `row-fluid` inside the `modal-body`, and then 2 `span6` inside that..

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row-fluid">
   <form class="span6">
   </form>
   <div class="span6">
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You may also want to increase the default width of the modal..

```
.modal {
    width:45%;
    left:45%;
}
```

Demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/69517

Comment: Thanks i will look over that tomorrow.